# error writing to database with curl

Tags: curl

I am having an error message on attempts to create a JSON document on existing in database.
My commands in curl:

```
C:\Users\totti>curl -X POST -u <username> https://<account>.cloudant.com/businesscard -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"_id":"emp103", "name":"mark"}"
```

the error message is :

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

Any Suggestions?

kindest regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined many solution together ($no_proxy and double quote escaping) together to finally POST data to the database.
Here is what worked:

```
curl --noproxy '*' -X POST -u <username> "https://<account>.cloudant.com/employee" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d {"""foo""":"""bar"""}
```